# Access virtual server with no Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a virtual server with 1 and 1.  I always used to access this using Remote Desktop however all of a sudden this has 'died'.  The server has been rebooted but this has not fixed the issue.  I am now unable to get onto my server to even try and fix this and 1 and 1 support have stopped answering my emails.  I was able to VNC in for a short while however this has also now stopped.

Is there any way I can get access to any part of the server to try and figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Short of 1&1 involvement.  Your alternative is to find a new virtual server vendor.

Maybe 1&1 can reimage your virtual machine and see if that works.

Comment: Pretty much the lines I have been working along.  I have a new vendor however I need to be able to get on as my backups aren't exactly recent (another gripe...).  Reimaging not an option as data would be lost, I'd rather just leave them